# SQL Server renaming tables with contraints

Tags: sql-server, table-rename, sp-rename

very simple predicament I am in.

Basically I have four tables with primary/foreign keys and cascade constraints something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [Board]
(
 [BoardId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [BoardId] )
,[Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
,[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL
,[PortalId] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY ( [PortalId] ) REFERENCES Portals ( [PortalID] ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
,[OrganizerId] [int] NOT NULL
,[GroupId] [int] NULL
,[ModuleId] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY ( [ModuleId] ) REFERENCES Modules ( [ModuleID] ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
,[CreatedByUserId] [int] NOT NULL
,[CreatedOnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
,[LastModifiedByUserId] [int] NULL
,[LastModifiedOnDate] [datetime] NULL
)
GO
```

It has come to a point where I need to rename the original tables. I have renamed tables in the past using `sp_rename oldTableName, newTableName` but not tables with primary, foreign, and cascade constraints.

Is it safe enough to rename tables with `sp_rename` or should I resort to creating tables from scratch, copying data across and then dropping old tables?

Comment: As far as I know constraints are linked on the `objectid` and not the name. This means that you should not have a problem. What will cause a problem is that procedures, functions etc that reference that object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx

Comment: I already thought about that and converted all my procedures to server side code so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close off the question.

The solution I originally proposed of using `sp_rename oldTableName, newTableName` worked fine for me.

But as @jaques pointed out you need to be weary of any `stored procedures` that may be attached to these tables. Because stored procedure work off table names.